# Is there a way to navigate windows without CTRL-W + ... ie. from the command prompt?

Tags: key-bindings

I want to reclaim `CTRL-W` for closing my terminal tab to get the same behaviour
as in Firefox and other programs. Is there a command I can run to avoid having to press `CTRL-W`
to navigate windows in vim or neovim ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `:h windows.txt` you can find the following :

```
Note: All CTRL-W commands can also be executed with :wincmd, for those          
places where a Normal mode command can't be used or is inconvenient.
```

and

```
                                                :winc :wincmd                   
These commands can also be executed with ":wincmd":                             
                                                                                
:[count]winc[md] {arg}                                                          
                Like executing CTRL-W [count] {arg}.  Example:                  
                        :wincmd j                                               
                Moves to the window below the current one.                      
                This command is useful when a Normal mode cannot be used (for   
                the CursorHold autocommand event).  Or when a Normal mode       
                command is inconvenient.                                        
                The count can also be a window number.  Example:                
                        :exe nr . "wincmd w"                                    
                This goes to window "nr".
```

Comment: Note that you can accept your own answer to mark this as resolved.